# Loggers logging to 2 different outputs

Tags: python, logging, python-2.x

I want to create 2 loggers which logs to 2 different outputs in Python. This logger of mine is configured in a single module which will be used by 2 other main modules. My problem is since I configured the root logger to allow my logger to be used by 2 different main modules, I cannot separate logging output.

How can this be done?

Here is how I configure my logging:

```
# logger.py
import logging
def setup_logging():
    # If I give name to my getLogger, it will not be configuring root logger and my changes here cannot cascade to all other child loggers.
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    streamHandler = logging.StreamHandler()
    streamFormat = logging.Formatter('%(name)s - %(message)s')
    streamHandler.setFormatter(streamFormat)
    logger.addHandler(streamHandler)
```

```
# main1.py
import logging
from logger import setup_logging
from submodule import log_me

setup_logging()
logger = logging.getLogger('main1')

logger.log('I am from main1')
log_me()
```

```
# main2.py
import logging
from logger import setup_logging
from submodule import log_me

setup_logging()
logger = logging.getLogger('main2')

logger.log('I am from main2')
log_me()
```

```
# submodule.py
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('submodule')

def log_me():
    logger.info('I am from submodule')
```

Result from main1:

```
main1 - I am from main1
submodule - I am from submodule
```

Result from main2:

```
main2 - I am from main2
submodule - I am from submodule
```

---

Here is what I am trying to achieve (but beautifully fails of course).

```
# logger.py
import logging
def setup_logging():
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    streamHandler = logging.StreamHandler()
    streamFormat = logging.Formatter('%(name)s - %(message)s')
    streamHandler.setFormatter(streamFormat)
    logger.addHandler(streamHandler)

def setup_second_logging():
    logger2 = logging.getLogger()
    fileHandler = logging.FileHandler('./out.log)
    fileFormat = logging.Formatter('%(name)s - %(message)s')
    fileHandler.setFormatter(fileFormat)
    logger.addHandler(fileHandler)
```

**--same main1.py--**

**--same main2.py--**

```
# submodule.py
import logging
from logger import setup_second_logging

setup_second_logging()

logger = logging.getLogger('submodule')

def log_me():
    logger.info('I am from submodule')
```

Result from main1:

```
main1 - I am from main1
# no submodule since it is logged to file
```

Result from main2:

```
main2 - I am from main2
# no submodule since it is logged to file
```

Comment: Look into the propagate option for the submodule logger.

Comment: I am aware that propagate can stop other logger with other names from propagating to our main one. But I think cannot be used here since configuring root logger applies the logging option for all child logger.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [hierarchy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logger-objects) for the loggers. For example:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

And in this case you can set specific handlers for the submodules in `logger.py`.

Comment: That'd make my  main logger's name to be __main__ and I cant customize the name.